# defer img loading / CSP: allow embeded img

Tags: html, http, content-security-policy

My website is defering some img loading by setting the img src value by JavaScript (from the img data-src value). In order to have still valid HTML as long as the URL is not set to img src, I am setting src to an inline embeded img like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs="
data-src="URL-TO-REAL-IMAGE.png">
```

This works fine, but shows an error at the browser console (Firefox, Chrome):

> Refused to load the image
>   'data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=' because
>   it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self' * 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'img-src' was not
>   explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Shouldn't **'unsafe-inline'** allow exactly this? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://content-security-policy.com/ you need to use the CSP

```
img-src 'self' data:
```

> Allows loading resources via the data scheme (eg Base64 encoded images).

`unsafe-inline` appears to be only relevant for javascript sources, not image sources.